# FeedAttachment: INVALID_OPERATION, Cannot create, update or delete Feed Attachment

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed

In Apex, I'm trying to insert a `FeedItem` then a `FeedAttachment` so the Chatter post has a file related with it. However, when trying to follow the [example in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm) I'm getting this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OPERATION, Cannot create, update or delete Feed Attachment

## Sample Code from Documentation

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Upon re-reading the [FeedAttachment documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm) there is this notice under **Special Access Rules**:

> You can read, create, update, or delete a FeedAttachment only if you have the corresponding access to the associated FeedItem.

Apparently, when inserting a `FeedAttachment` this is considered an **update** to the `FeedItem`. Therefore, you need **Allow users to edit posts and comments** enabled under **Setup | Customize | Chatter | Chatter Settings**.

[image]

*Fun Fact: You can insert multiple `FeedAttachment`'s to a single `FeedItem` Chatter post. So you can associate File(s) and up to one URL link with the post.*